# ggplot reports a continuous variable is categorical; what am I missing?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to loop through a dataframe and based on whether the column is a factor or a number return a faceted ggplot.

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- mtcars 
# make a couple factors
d2 <- d %>% mutate_at((vars(matches("cyl"),matches("gear"))), as.factor)
#check
(d2 %>% map_lgl(is.factor))
(d2 %>% map_lgl(is.numeric))
```

This works:

```
plot_chart <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE){
  nm = names(df)
  for (i in nm) {
    nm_p <- grep(paste("^",i,"$",sep=""), nm)  #finds the position of i in the sequence
    g <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = i))
    print(nm_p) # progress to console
    if (is.factor(df[,nm_p])==TRUE) {
        g <- g + geom_bar()
      } else if (is.numeric(df[,nm_p])) {
        g <- g + geom_histogram(bins = 10)
      }
    g <- g + facet_wrap(~cyl,nrow=1) + labs( x = i)
    print(g) 

    # indexes and saves
    # idx <- paste(sprintf("%04d", nm_p), "_Cyl_by_", i,".svg", sep="")
    # ggsave(idx , device="svg", width = 10, height = 10, units = "cm")
  }
}

plot_chart(d2)  #Success!
```

However, trying to abstract the function further (with the eventual goal of adding additional chart types and finessing the input), fails:

```
callplot <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE){
  nm = names(df)
  for (i in nm) {
    #finds the position of i in the sequence
    nm_p <- grep(paste("^",i,"$",sep=""), nm)
    # print(nm_p) # progress to console
    if (is.factor(df[,nm_p])==TRUE) {
      t <- "fac"
    } else if (is.numeric(df[,nm_p])) {
      t <- "num"
    }
    plotme(df, i, t)
  }
}

plotme <- function(df, x, type, na.rm = TRUE){
  xq <- enquo(x)
  g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = !! xq))
  if (type=="fac") {
    g <- g + geom_bar()
  } else if (type=="num") {
    print(x)   
    g <- g + geom_histogram(bins=10) #<--- fails here 
  }
  g +  facet_wrap(~cyl,nrow=1) + labs( x = x)
  print(g)
}

callplot(d2)
```

The error is:

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable: the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

However, `mpg` is a number not a factor, as the logic dictates. Is this to do with `enquo` and `!!`? Those represent a whole new level of confusion to me.

What am I missing?

Comment: you can always pass in strings vs symbols and use `aes_string()` to remove the complexity associated with non-standard evaluation.

Comment: Since you are passing strings as aesthetics you'll want `ensym()` in place of `enquo()`.